# Ruby and nil object

Tags: ruby

I'm new to ruby world and i'm currently studying it.  I have read over the google about `nil` object, but still can`t figure out what it is ?

Can anyone explain me in more details or share some link for further reading ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`nil` is the one and only instance of the `NilClass` class. It doesn't have any special behavior (other than the fact that it's interpreted as false in a boolean context (e.g. in an `if` condition), as Andrew Grimm helpfully pointed out). The purpose of `nil` is to signify "no result".

For example a method which is supposed to find an item meeting a certain condition would return `nil` if there is no item that meets the condition. Or accessing the `i`th element of an array which has less than `i` elements will return `nil`.

It has a similar purpose to the null pointer in other languages, except that you can call `Object` methods (i.e. methods which are defined on every object) on it without causing an exception.

Comment: One somewhat special behaviour of `nil` is that it's the only object that lacks truthiness apart from `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Think of nil as null. But since everything in Ruby is an object, nil is the only instance of singleton class NilClass. Then, nil responds to methods and can be monkey patched. In fact, you can do anything you can do to any other class (taking into account that it is singleton).